# Can't get FB authorization to work correctly

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

http://apps.facebook.com/karmabalance/

I am trying to get the login and authorization working on my FB App, but it seems to do funny stuff. Basically all I want is when the user clicks on my app, I want fb to do their check to make sure they are logged in and have approved the app, and after that I need the program to do a check of the database to see if their is already a record in the database with the User FB ID. If their is no record, I want the program to send the user to a create acct. page that will enable the user to enter a Username. If there is a record, I want to send the user to the app home page.

I thought I got it to work, but its still not right, and I can't figure out why. Here is my code. I'm sure there is a better way to do this also, I am a newbie, so I'm trying to figure this all out as I go. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

When the user clicks my app it goes to this index.php page.

```
<?php 
require 'config.php';

session_start();

$usercheck = $user_profile['id'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT FBID FROM PLAYER WHERE (FBID = '$usercheck') ");

if ($facebook->getUser()) 
{ 

    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        header('location: Home.php');
    } else 
    { ?>
         <p>Please choose a Username for yourself. </p>
            <form action='includes/signup.php' method='post'>
            <fieldset style="width:600px";>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input name='username' type='text' value='<? if ($facebook->getUser()) 
                    {echo'Choose a Username';} ?>' />

            <input name='submit' type='submit' value='submit' />
            </fieldset>
            </form>
     <? }
} else 
  { ?>
   <p>Sign up with Facebook <fb:login-button perms='email'> Connect</fb:login-button>

It only takes a few seconds</p>

<div id='fb-root'></div>

      <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

      <script>

         FB.init({ 

            appId:'334230339967350', cookie:true, 

            status:true, xfbml:true 

         });

         FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {

        window.location.reload(); //will reload your page you are on

      });

      </script>
  <? }

?>
```

The config file:

```
<?php 
//Facebook Configuration
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$app_secret = "xxxxxxx";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($user) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


//SQL Configuration

 // i start most if not all pages with this depending on what Im using it for.

    $host = 'localhost'; // host name OR IP

    $username = 'security';//username

    $pass = 'blockedout'; //password

    $dbname    = 'Security'; // Database Name

    $conn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $pass) or die(mysql_error());

    if ($conn)

    {

        mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

    }

    else

    {

       echo 'Connection failed.';

    } // The above code connects to your database or errors if it cannot connect.

// Again this is simple, security is your own priority.

//GLOBAL VALUES??

$usercheck = $user_profile['id'];

$usernamequery = mysql_query("SELECT UserName FROM PLAYER WHERE (FBID = '$usercheck') ");
$username = mysql_fetch_array($usernamequery);

$levelquery = mysql_query("SELECT LevelID FROM PLAYER WHERE (FBID = '$usercheck') ");
$level = mysql_fetch_array($levelquery);


$result = mysql_query("SELECT FBID FROM PLAYER WHERE (FBID = '$usercheck') ");


?>
```

And here is the signup.php page

```
<?

require_once '../config.php';



//here you could add checks for any empty fields using (!($_POST['first_name']))

$first_name = $user_profile['first_name']; // this line will collect our information from the

// field in our form that has the facebook first_name in it.

$last_name = $user_profile['last_name']; // same as above

$email = $user_profile['email']; //same as above

$id = $user_profile['id']; //same as above

$username1 = $_POST['username'];

$query = mysql_query
        ("
        INSERT INTO PLAYER (FirstName, LastName, EMail, FBID, UserName, Status, LevelID, Cash, LifePoints, RespectPoints, ReputationPoints, UpgradePoints, HealthPercent) 
        VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email', '$id', '$username1', '1', '1', '25000', '3', '3', '3', '20', '100')
        ") 
        or die(mysql_error());

// The query will insert our fields in to the database as the above line shows, make 

//sure your database table headers are exactly correct otherwise this will not work



// You can now either send an email or if you wanted header to a new page. This is 

//up to you. Tutorials on google will show you how to do this part

if($query){

header('location: ../Home.php');

}else {

echo 'error adding to database';    

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the oauth token for the user. thats the handle of the user you want to pull. 
if you are still confuse, let me know.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, i thought I was doing that with 

`// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
`

Perhaps you could point me in the right direction to start researching it more?